# YAML set a value on a parameter with a variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

is it possible to set a value on a parameter or to define the default value with the valiable.

e.g.

```
parameters:
- name: paraA
  type: boolean
  default: true
  value: $(variableA)
#variableA is set in a yaml build in azure devops and for some build it should false and not true
```

```
parameters:
- name: paraA
  type: boolean
  default: ${{ if eq(variable.variableA, false) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know it's not supported scenario. [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax) like `variableA` are expanded at runtime while [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) like `paraA` are expanded at template parsing time.

When [processing one pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline), it first expands templates and evaluate template expressions before expanding the runtime variables. The document has stated this:

[image]